# How to make popup appear underneath a Button -Android

Tags: android, xml, popup

How can I make a popup appear under a Button instead of an exact location? Currently this is my code that sets where the popup appears,

```
popUpFollowUsername.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.dashboardRelative), Gravity.TOP, 100, 280);
```

I want it to appear directly underneath a button which is this button

```
<Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/post"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@drawable/dashboard_post"
        android:id="@+id/btnPost"/>
```

I have multiple android phones and the popup appears at different locations on every phone, how can I make it always appear directly under the post Button?

Comment: Use @rekire's answer as `popUpFollowUsername.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.dashboardRelative), Gravity.TOP, 0, y);`. This should work if your `R.id.dashboardRelative` has layout_width set to match_parent. Else, you may need to adjust the x value to horizontally center the popup.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`View.getLocationOnScreen()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen%28int%5B%5D%29) and/or [`View.getLocationInWindow()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationInWindow%28int%5B%5D%29), so you will be able to get the position of the view on the screen. With this information it should be easy to put the popup near to the button.

Basically use something like that: (not tested)

```java
Button btn = get(); // maybe with findViewById
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    void onClick(View v) {
        int[] pos = new int[2];
        v.getLocationInWindow(pos);
        int x = pos[0];
        int y = pos[1] + v.getHeight();
        // show popup at the given x,y position
    }
});
```

Comment: I dont want the popup near the bottom, I want it under the postbutton

Comment: Add the height of the button to the y ordinate and you have what you want.